# what is the purpose of assertThat in JDBI?

Tags: java, jdbi

I am going through a codebase that I found in github.
I found a set of lines in the code that contains the following function:`assertThat`.Any help is appreciated.

```
 myObject = someDao.foo(obj);
 assertThat(myObject.getUpdated,isAfter(updated));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an assertion from a lib called [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) used to ensure certain states in a program. If they fail they throw an Exception with some output to help understanding what goes wrong. Its like assert or the assertEquals methods from [JUnit](http://junit.org/). And so they are normally used in a test class but you can also use them in a normal program to ensure states you expect (Preconditions, Postconditions,Class Invariants or Design by contract).

So this ensures the `Date getUpdated`> `Date updated` when this is wrong the Exception is thrown.